# Shortcut list txt for node wrangler

Tags: node-editor, shortcut

does anyone know if there s a shortcut list (txt) for the node wrangler (not the list in the preferences). There s a lot of helpful shortcuts in this addon but i find it annoying to go to the preferences all the time. i d like to put the shortcuts in a txt note in my node editor until i learned all the ones i need...Thanks for your help 
mooopstar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into the addon's code, grab the kmi_defs and print the variables.

```
for kmi in kmi_defs:
    print(kmi[len(kmi)-1].ljust(60), end="")
    if (kmi[1]):
        print("Ctrl ", end ="")
    if (kmi[2]):
        print("Shift ", end ="")
    if (kmi[3]):
        print("Alt ", end ="")
    print(kmi[0])
```

This is the output.

```
Merge Nodes (Automatic)                                     Ctrl Shift NUMPAD_0
Merge Nodes (Automatic)                                     Ctrl Shift ZERO
Merge Nodes (Add)                                           Ctrl Shift NUMPAD_PLUS
Merge Nodes (Add)                                           Ctrl Shift EQUAL
Merge Nodes (Multiply)                                      Ctrl Shift NUMPAD_ASTERIX
Merge Nodes (Multiply)                                      Ctrl Shift EIGHT
Merge Nodes (Subtract)                                      Ctrl Shift NUMPAD_MINUS
Merge Nodes (Subtract)                                      Ctrl Shift MINUS
Merge Nodes (Divide)                                        Ctrl Shift NUMPAD_SLASH
Merge Nodes (Divide)                                        Ctrl Shift SLASH
Merge Nodes (Less than)                                     Ctrl Shift COMMA
Merge Nodes (Greater than)                                  Ctrl Shift PERIOD
Merge Nodes (Z-Combine)                                     Ctrl Shift NUMPAD_PERIOD
Merge Nodes (Alpha Over)                                    Ctrl Shift NUMPAD_0
Merge Nodes (Alpha Over)                                    Ctrl Shift ZERO
Merge Nodes (Color, Add)                                    Ctrl Shift NUMPAD_PLUS
Merge Nodes (Color, Add)                                    Ctrl Shift EQUAL
Merge Nodes (Color, Multiply)                               Ctrl Shift NUMPAD_ASTERIX
Merge Nodes (Color, Multiply)                               Ctrl Shift EIGHT
Merge Nodes (Color, Subtract)                               Ctrl Shift NUMPAD_MINUS
Merge Nodes (Color, Subtract)                               Ctrl Shift MINUS
Merge Nodes (Color, Divide)                                 Ctrl Shift NUMPAD_SLASH
Merge Nodes (Color, Divide)                                 Ctrl Shift SLASH
Merge Nodes (Math, Add)                                     Ctrl Shift Alt NUMPAD_PLUS
Merge Nodes (Math, Add)                                     Ctrl Shift Alt EQUAL
Merge Nodes (Math, Multiply)                                Ctrl Shift Alt NUMPAD_ASTERIX
Merge Nodes (Math, Multiply)                                Ctrl Shift Alt EIGHT
Merge Nodes (Math, Subtract)                                Ctrl Shift Alt NUMPAD_MINUS
Merge Nodes (Math, Subtract)                                Ctrl Shift Alt MINUS
Merge Nodes (Math, Divide)                                  Ctrl Shift Alt NUMPAD_SLASH
Merge Nodes (Math, Divide)                                  Ctrl Shift Alt SLASH
Merge Nodes (Math, Less than)                               Ctrl Shift Alt COMMA
Merge Nodes (Math, Greater than)                            Ctrl Shift Alt PERIOD
Batch change blend type (Mix)                               Ctrl NUMPAD_0
Batch change blend type (Mix)                               Ctrl ZERO
Batch change blend type (Add)                               Ctrl NUMPAD_PLUS
Batch change blend type (Add)                               Ctrl EQUAL
Batch change blend type (Multiply)                          Ctrl NUMPAD_ASTERIX
Batch change blend type (Multiply)                          Ctrl EIGHT
Batch change blend type (Subtract)                          Ctrl NUMPAD_MINUS
Batch change blend type (Subtract)                          Ctrl MINUS
Batch change blend type (Divide)                            Ctrl NUMPAD_SLASH
Batch change blend type (Divide)                            Ctrl SLASH
Batch change blend type (Current)                           Ctrl COMMA
Batch change blend type (Current)                           Ctrl PERIOD
Batch change blend type (Next)                              Ctrl DOWN_ARROW
Batch change blend type (Previous)                          Ctrl UP_ARROW
Link active to selected (Don't replace links)               Ctrl K
Link active to selected (Replace links)                     Ctrl Alt K
Link active to selected (Don't replace links, node names)   Ctrl QUOTE
Link active to selected (Replace links, node names)         Ctrl Alt QUOTE
Link active to selected (Don't replace links, output names) Ctrl SEMI_COLON
Link active to selected (Replace links, output names)       Ctrl Alt SEMI_COLON
Reduce Mix Factor by 0.1                                    Ctrl LEFT_ARROW
Increase Mix Factor by 0.1                                  Ctrl RIGHT_ARROW
Reduce Mix Factor by 0.01                                   Ctrl Alt LEFT_ARROW
Increase Mix Factor by 0.01                                 Ctrl Alt RIGHT_ARROW
Set Mix Factor to 0.0                                       Ctrl Shift Alt LEFT_ARROW
Set Mix Factor to 1.0                                       Ctrl Shift Alt RIGHT_ARROW
Set Mix Factor to 0.0                                       Ctrl Shift Alt NUMPAD_0
Set Mix Factor to 0.0                                       Ctrl Shift Alt ZERO
Mix Factor to 1.0                                           Ctrl Shift Alt NUMPAD_1
Set Mix Factor to 1.0                                       Ctrl Shift Alt ONE
Clear node labels                                           Ctrl L
Modify node labels                                          Ctrl Alt L
Copy label from active to selected                          Ctrl Alt V
Detach outputs                                              Ctrl Alt D
Link to output node                                         Ctrl O
Select children                                             Ctrl RIGHT_BRACKET
Select Parent                                               Ctrl LEFT_BRACKET
Add texture setup                                           Ctrl Shift T
Add Principled texture setup                                Ctrl Shift Alt T
Reset backdrop image zoom                                   Ctrl Z
Delete unused nodes                                         Ctrl X
Frame selected nodes                                        Ctrl Alt P
Swap Outputs                                                Ctrl S
Connect to Cycles Viewer node                               Ctrl Shift Alt LEFTMOUSE
Reload images                                               Ctrl R
Lazy Mix                                                    Ctrl RIGHTMOUSE
Lazy Connect                                                Ctrl Shift RIGHTMOUSE
Lazy Connect with Socket Menu                               Ctrl Shift Alt RIGHTMOUSE
Set Viewers Tile Center                                     Ctrl LEFTMOUSE
Align selected nodes neatly in a row/column                 Ctrl Alt EQUAL
Revert node back to default state, but keep connections     Ctrl BACK_SPACE
Node Wranger menu                                           Ctrl Shift Alt wm.call_menu
Add Reroutes menu                                           Ctrl Shift wm.call_menu
Add Reroutes menu                                           Ctrl Shift wm.call_menu
Link active to selected (menu)                              Ctrl Shift wm.call_menu
Copy to selected (menu)                                     Ctrl Shift wm.call_menu
Switch node type menu                                       Ctrl Shift wm.call_menu
```

Comment: Hi, what does the wm.call_menu mean? I'm interested in this particular shortcut: Node Wranger menu: Ctrl Shift Alt wm.call_menu, but what is wm.call_menu in Blender 2.8?