# What shortcut to open Node Wrangler menu in 2.8?

Tags: node-editor, shortcut

I need the shortcut that will open the Node Wrangler menu in 2.8. I found this thread: [Shortcut list txt for node wrangler](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96064/shortcut-list-txt-for-node-wrangler) from 2017. It says <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>wm.call_menu</kbd>. But what is `wm.call_menu`?? Anyway, I need a shortcut valid for Blender 2.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortcut for the Node Wrangler's Quick access menu in 2.8 is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.
Shortcut for Node Wrangler's Quick access menu in 2.79 is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>.

You can also press <kbd>T</kbd> to open Properties shelf on the right in 2.8 or <kbd>N</kbd> to open Toolshelf on the left in 2.79 and prior and open Node Wrangler addon's tab; there you will find all the tools it provides with shortcuts shown if you hover over them as well as the Quick Access shortcut  written in the top.

[image]

I don't have any idea what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>wm.call_menu</kbd> actually is; `wm.call_menu` is a command entered into RNA field in the user prefs shortcut dialog and has nothing to do with a shortcut itself, it's a way to tell Blender menu with some choices should appear. The source for the choices is then pointed out in the *Name* field.